# Why am I getting Syntax Error for my query?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I wrote this query in mongoDB to find movies with no actors listed, but it is giving a syntax error.

This is the query:

```
db.title_page.findOne({"cast.role" : { $not : {"actor"} } } , {_id : false, title : true})
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting the error.

I am getting this error:

> 2019-01-24T05:36:33.119+0100 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:54

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `$not` in mongo should be like.

```
db.inventory.find( { price: { $not: { $gt: 1.99 } } } )
```

But in your case try use `$ne`.

In term of mysql it will work like not equal to.

```
db.getCollection('cast').find({
  role: { 
    $ne: "actor" 
  }
  }, 
  {
   _id:0,
    title:1    
  }
)
```